# Proper way of implementing night mode feature

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-night-mode

I know by using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` night mode can be implemented in an activity. But what I want is that - there'll be an option in settings for activating night mode in all the activities & fragment in the app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One way to achieve this:**

- When you select the action night mode in setting activity(or any) you
  can maintain a flag(& save in sharedpreference or any temp storage).
- Check this flag on each and every activity & fragment and if the flag
  is positive set the night mode as you used,

  AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

Comment: Correct! I just followed this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NightModeHelper](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/c508cdc8828a478572e0) to achieve this, just add the following line at the top of your activity's `onCreate` just after `super.onCreate();` The idea here is to do it before we create any views. So the new views will use the correct Configuration.

```
mNightModeHelper = new NightModeHelper(this, R.style.AppTheme);
```

See a demo here https://github.com/zouliping/AndroidNightMode